# PostgreSQL: Insert records into other tables that have a reference from the main table

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I want to achieve such that after executing the query:

```
INSERT INTO accounts (unique_id) VALUES ('c78f139a-7d71-429b-b55c-0d8fad481959')
```

the accound_id and initial value are automatically inserted into all other tables that have a common structure.

Here are all the tables I have:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts(
    unique_id uuid,
    account_id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    PRIMARY KEY (unique_id, account_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS currency_golden_credit (
    ref_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES accounts(account_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    balance INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_account FOREIGN KEY (ref_id) 
      REFERENCES accounts (account_id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS currency_iron_credit (
    ref_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES accounts(account_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    balance INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_account FOREIGN KEY (ref_id) 
      REFERENCES accounts (account_id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I didn't find any solution and tried the query, but it also turned out to be incorrect:

```
with rows as (
  INSERT INTO accounts (unique_id) VALUES
    ('c78f139a-7d71-429b-b55c-0d8fad481959')
    RETURNING account_id
) 

INSERT INTO currency_golden_credit (ref_id) SELECT account_id
INSERT INTO currency_iron_credit (ref_id) SELECT account_id
FROM rows;
```

Comment: 2 tables, with the same structure, just a different name, smells like an issue in the data model. What happens when you add "silver" or "platinum" ? You need a new table. Put everything in a single table, with just a reference to the type of metal and you can support all metals

Comment: @FrankHeikens the problem is that in the future new currencies may be added or old ones may be cleared, then you will have to constantly change the structure of the table, which I think is not very good

Comment: No, a currency is just a currency, just another piece of data in your record. You don't need different tables or columns for different currencies. You need 2 columns, balance and currency. Now you support every currency you can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Frank Heikens mentioned, you need to review the model you are working with.Your attempt is on the right track. However, you need to modify the query to ensure that the account_id generated from the main table insertion is used in the subsequent inserts into the other tables.

```sql
WITH rows AS (
  INSERT INTO accounts (unique_id) VALUES ('c78f139a-7d71-429b-b55c-0d8fad481959')
  RETURNING account_id
) 
INSERT INTO currency_golden_credit (ref_id) SELECT account_id FROM rows
INSERT INTO currency_iron_credit (ref_id) SELECT account_id FROM rows;
```

In this query below, I used the `RETURNING` clause after the insertion into the `accounts` table to retrieve the generated `account_id`. The `WITH` clause assigns the returned `account_id` to the `rows` CTE (Common Table Expression).

Then, I added the subsequent `INSERT` statements into the other tables `currency_golden_credit` and `currency_iron_credit` using a `SELECT` statement from the `rows` CTE to obtain the `account_id`.

Comment: an error occurs on the second insert into and the request is not executed

Comment: What is the error you are getting?